# Adding custom tag with TinyMCE using ed.selection.setContent

Tags: tinymce

I'm trying to add a custom tag to content selected in the editor, but `<title>` content `</title>` does not work.  This works though:  `[title]` content `[/title]`

Googling leads me to believe that I need to use these lines as well, but it does not help:

```
extended_valid_elements : "title",
custom_elements: "title",
```

Example:

For some reason this code does not work:

```
setup : function(ed) {
    // Add a custom button
    ed.addButton('mybutton', {
    title : 'My button',
    'class' : 'Mybutton',
    image : 'img/example.gif',
    onclick : function() {
        // Add you own code to execute something on click
        ed.focus();
        ed.selection.setContent("<title>" + ed.selection.getContent() + '</title>');

    }
```

But this works:

```
setup : function(ed) {
    // Add a custom button
    ed.addButton('mybutton', {
    title : 'My button',
    'class' : 'Mybutton',
    image : 'img/example.gif',
    onclick : function() {
        // Add you own code to execute something on click
        ed.focus();
        ed.selection.setContent("[title]" + ed.selection.getContent() + '[/title]');

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the way to go

```
extended_valid_elements : "title",
custom_elements: "title",
```

You do not see anything because title is not defined elsewhere than in the head.
You will find your title-tag using firebug and it will hold what you expect to hold (ed.selection.getContent() wrapped into a title-tag.):

Comment: I was using "title" instead of my specific tag so it may have mislead your answer.  Let's just say that the tag is called "abc" --- and I have that in the extended_valid_elements and custom_elements setting.  I still can't seem to create that in tag in the textarea that I have defined.  The idea is that the user will see a descriptive tag in the textarea field when adding content.  Is that possible with TinyMCE?

Comment: I see what you're saying btw with regards to Firebug and how the tag will hold the content that I expect.  That part seems to work.  I just want the same tag to show up in the UI because it's helpful to the user.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: there is a way, but it is not very elegeant, you may use jQuery (or get the node usign document.getelementBy...) to get get UI node and add a html node there where you can display messages, description and whatever you like. well, of course you will need to take care of the style and look of the UI