# TinyMCE formatting button

Tags: wordpress, button, tinymce

Im using Wordpress on my Webpages and now i have decided to post there some tutorials and posts about it, and i just need some button that can open a box with options and i need to make starting tag using these options, and after selected put the closing tag. Im not really good in JS so i understand only a bit.

---

I found this:
http://return-true.com/2011/12/adding-tinymce-button-to-wordpress-via-plugin-part-2/
[Adding custom tag with TinyMCE using ed.selection.setContent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265024/adding-custom-tag-with-tinymce-using-ed-selection-setcontent)
maybe i need only to combine these two solutions

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using an own plugin. Your plugin needs a button and this button will trigger a tinymce command that you will have to define. This command will open the box.

Developing an own plugin is pretty easy: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Creating_a_plugin
You should get the tinymce development version from the moxiecode download page. Check out the plugins directory for a plugin that uses a popup/model dialog - i think something like the searchreplace plugin will help.

Comment: I've tried to make it from the plugin SH TinyMCE button, but its so sophisticated for me to understand. I made throw the tutorial on return-true.com, but it's only to generate shortcode and re-write the selection - i need to close this tag after end of selection...

Comment: you ma<y also try to use a tinymce fiddle and insert your action stuff inside a setup configuration parameter: fiddle.tinymce.com/

Comment: Ok Ill only try to make plugin, that i have to write text in, and itll generate it whole, i dont understand it. Thank you ;)